# How to display data from mysql PHP NOT in table but in paragraph

Tags: php, mysql, html, session

As written in the tittle I would like the data to be displayed in paragraph not in a table. Can please anyone help me. This is my working code, data is displayed in a table. BUT I would like to be displayed in paragraphs not in tr/th.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl-PL">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Content</th>
</tr>    
<?php
session_start();
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array();
$_SESSION['success'] = "";

$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'cms');
 ?>

<?php

$query ="SELECT * FROM articles";

$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

         if($result->num_rows > 0) {

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo "<tr><td>" .$row['article_content'] ."</td><tr>";

            }
        }
 ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Replace what you need with `<p>`/`</p>`.

Comment: You print it in a table with your `<tr>` and `<td>` tags. Remove those and `<table>`, then use `<p>` instead around your `echo` inside the loop?

Comment: This is HTML 101.

Comment: Enable error reporting; your system is most likely suppressing errors. You are outputting before header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your HTML to remove the table-related code, and replace it with paragraph elements. Note that your `session_start` is going to fail with your existing code as it will attempt to send headers but PHP will have already sent headers as soon as it encountered the HTML in the document. So you need to move the `session_start` code to the beginning of the file.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl-PL">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Content</h1>  
<?php
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array();
$_SESSION['success'] = "";

$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'cms');
//Create the select query
$query ="SELECT * FROM articles"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    //Loop through results
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<p>" .$row['article_content'] ."</p>";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note: OP's system may be suppressing errors and are outputting before header.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner surely headers are sent as soon as the first HTML is encountered (and long before the PHP in this example)?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner ah I see your point now - the `session_start` is going to fail if it is using cookies.

Comment: That's right Nick. :)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks for that. I've edited the code appropriately.

Comment: You're quite welcome Nick, *cheers*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<p>" .$row['article_content'] ."</p>";
```

remove table tags from the file.

Comment: How is this different from the answer I already posted?